# Was the public made aware of what happened to Jean Grey in "Dark Phoenix"?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-dark-phoenix

During *Dark Phoenix* public opinion on mutants (or at least X-Men) shifts back from hard-earned respect to fear and mistrust, after Jean Grey is unable to control what is happening to her, and assaults police officers and her fellow X-Men. Obviously people are clueless about what was actually going on, (Phoenix Force and all) and assumed it was just Jean going rogue.

I don't remember other mutants attempting to explain why Jean did that; then again, they had more pressing matters to handle, saving Jean, stopping the bad guys, etc.

However at the end

> Jean defeats Vuk and fuses with the Phoenix Force and takes off, Xavier retires from the X-Men life, Beast takes over as headmaster of the newly renamed "Jean Grey school", etc.

After that I'd be surprised, given all the effort of Xavier and the others to earn people's trust, if they didn't try to explain the situation, if only to cleanse Jean's image. On the other hand, that's not clear by the end of the movie.

Is there any information about that, from interviews, novelizations or other? (As *Dark Phoenix* is supposed to be the end of the current X-Men franchise, I don't think our future works policy applies to that question.)

Google queries like `did they reveal what happened to jean grey dark phoenix` don't seem to yield anything particularly relevant (for me, at least).

Comment: “they had more pressing matters to handle, saving Jean, stopping the bad guys etc.” — desperately trying to get Kevin Feige’s number as their agent is being no help whatsoever.

Comment: In a fairly self-referential move, they made a film about it, but hardly anyone bothered to go see it :(